# trying to implement listview inside onclick function

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

```
public class CompanySearchActivity extends RathbonesActivity {
private CompanySearchAdapter mStockListAdapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.companysearch_layout);
    final EditText keywordET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.codeET);
    final Button search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_stock_add);
    final Activity a= CompanySearchActivity.this;
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String keyword = keywordET.getText().toString();
            Log.i("keyword: ",keyword);
            ArrayList codearr = getResults(keyword);
            mStockListAdapter = new CompanySearchAdapter(a,codearr);

            ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.stocklist);
            listview.setAdapter(mStockListAdapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        }
    });


}
```

The lines `listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);` are giving errors because of this keyword, i replaced it with 'a' too but it doesnt work. What can be the possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use the parent activities onClick method your activity must implement OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener

```
public class CompanySearchActivity extends RathbonesActivity implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener 
{
     @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

Note the code "`implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener`"
This is vital for implementing it this way.

Then you can call:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(CompanySearchActivity.this);
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(CompanySearchActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is a reference to the object that owns the currently executing method. In this case `this` refers to the anonymous `View.OnClickListener` object that you are defining. Try replacing `this` with `CompanySearchActivity.this`

Answer (score 0):

your `listview` onClick definition should look like your search listener.

```
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {






       search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String keyword = keywordET.getText().toString();
            Log.i("keyword: ",keyword);
            ArrayList codearr = getResults(keyword);
            mStockListAdapter = new CompanySearchAdapter(a,codearr);
        }
    });

   ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.stocklist);
   listview.setAdapter(mStockListAdapter);

   listview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
<do somthing when its clicked>
        }
    });
```

also ensure if you have multiple layouts that these view items (listview and search)
 are in companysearch_layout.xml

Comment: why though are u makeing the listview clickable within the onclick method of search?  normally the onclicklisteners are done separate.

Comment: to reiterate my comment above: why are you setting an onclicklistener inside of another onclicklistener definition.  if there is not reason then get it out of there.

Comment: redid my example to illustrate what i said above